# How to calculate the bandwidth when 2 pages has similar content?

Tags: image, caching, browser, server, bandwidth

I have two pages: `Page1` and `Page2`.
On these two pages, I have the same image: `Image1`.

If I visit `Page1` and the browser cache the image and I then visit `Page2`, will the browser get the cached image or will it be downloaded again?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using virtual browser like puppeteer or selenium, you can use no cache mode/disable cache so nothing is cached. You can turn it on at your dev tools of your browser too (the network tab)